# Parent class using methods defined in child

Tags: design, python, python-3.x

I am working on a large program (more than 10k lines of code).

Below is a (hopefully not over-simplified) example of a problem I sometimes face:

```
class MyClass1(object):

    def func_1(self):
        return self.func_2() * 2


class MyClass6(MyClass1):

    def func_2(self):
        return 10


a = MyClass6().func_1()
print(a)  # Prints 20
```

I need to use in `MyClass1` a method that is defined later on in `MyClass6`.

---

Using this code as is, works fine. I get quite a visible warning:

[image]

and I can add a comment so that I know what is going on in the future in case I need to debug it. However, I can't use options in my IDE like <kbd>Find usages</kbd>, <kbd>Rename</kbd> etc.

---

Alternatively, I can use [`@abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/abc.html?highlight=abstractproperty#abc.abstractmethod) to make it explicit that `funct_2` is defined in a child class and my IDE options would work fine:

```
import abc


class MyClass1(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def func_2(self):
        return 'zzzz'

    def func_1(self):
        return self.func_2() * 2


class MyClass5(MyClass1):

    def func_2(self):
        return 10


a = MyClass5().func_1()
print(a)    # Prints 20
```

... but I think this is not the way to go. For example I get weak warnings from my IDE for classes inbetween `MyClass1` and `MyClass5` (e.g. "MyClass4 has to implement abstract method...").

---

**Question:**

What is the right way to deal with a parent class using a method that is defined in a child class?

**Edit**:
Some extra details: 
`MyClass1` is never called on its own. Also `func_2()` has to be defined in `MyClass6` because everything it needs is defined there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `func_2` in `MyClass1` doesn't contain any logic and is expected to be declared by child classes (and `MyClass1` is never used directly), then making the class abstract like you did is a reasonable approach and makes the code self-documenting and explicit.

If:

- `func_2` in `MyClass1` contains logic (eventually overwritten in child classes),
- Or `MyClass1` may be used as-is without any inheritance,
- Or a child should not be forced to implement `func_2`,

then declare `func_2` in `MyClass1`, containing the default logic (this is similar to virtual methods in other languages such as C#). In your case, it will return the default value. For methods which don't return anything, you may use `pass` keyword:

```
def func_2():
    pass
```

Finally, you may always rely on a dynamic nature of Python and let children deal with the declaration of `func_2`, expecting errors during runtime if the method is missing.

Comment: `MyClass1` is never called on its own. I guess I ll insert that in my question. As for using `pass`, i avoided it since it shows a yellow warning in some cases in `func_1`.

Comment: @user5061: when do you talk about warnings, do you mean warnings in your IDE? It looks like your editor reports warnings which are just informative rather than indicative of a error in your code.

Comment: I'm talking about IDE warnings. They might be simply informative, but it hinders refactoring since they are mixed with other important warnings (and I have to find which is which).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make it clear to the IDE and your users that there is a method, but you can't use the base class version:

```
class MyClass1(object):

    def func_2(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def func_1(self):
        return self.func_2() * 2
```

You won't get warnings from intermediate classes that don't define `func_2`, but will get an error if you call it on a class that hasn't overridden it. The other option, `pass`, can hide these errors in some cases.

Comment: I did not expect it, but my IDE produces the same warnings for your suggested solution as it does with `ABCMeta` solution: "Class MyClass4 has to implement abstract method...". Using another exception instead of `NotImplementedError` removes those warnings.

Answer (score -2):

If your problem is only the warnings of IDE, you can avoid it using 2 solutions

## solution 1, meta class

```
class ABCMeta():
    def func_2(self):
        return 1 #any valid value, just to your IDE dont complain

class MyClass1(ABCMeta):

    def func_1(self):
        return self.func_2() * 2


class MyClass5(MyClass1):

    def func_2(self):
        return 10 #the value you really want to use


a = MyClass5().func_1()
print(a)    # Prints 20
```

## solution 2, sintetic:

```
class MyClass1(ABCMeta):

    def func_2(self):
        return 1 #any valid value, just to your IDE dont complain

    def func_1(self):
        return self.func_2() * 2


class MyClass5(MyClass1):

    def func_2(self):
        return 10 #the value you really want to use
```

Comment: 1. Meta-class has a specific meaning, and that isn't it. 2. What does *sintetic* mean? Syntactic? Synthetic?